# MvvmCross Data Layer is unaccessible in case of Android App

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I am using the MvvmCross for application for android and Windows . We have one XML data file from where I am accessing the data and returning the list to Business Layer where that data is being operated and transferred to ViewModel via Service .

```
 public class Logic : ILogic
{

    #region Attributes

    List<Detail.Detail> _details = new List<Detail.Detail>();
    DataLayer.DataLayer dl = new DataLayer.DataLayer();

    #endregion

    #region .ctor

    public Logic()
    {

    }
  List<Detail.Detail> ILogic.Read()
    {

        _details = dl.Access();
        return _details;
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

> Above Code transfers the data to the ViewModel code given below .

```
 public class BookViewModel : MvxViewModel


 {


 public BookViewModel()
   {
       var aa = Mvx.Resolve<ILogic>();
       this.logic = aa;
      _details = logic.Read();

   }
}
```

Now the code is giving this error :

> Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and
>   initialize ViewModel for type ViewModels.ViewModels.BookViewModel from
>   locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check MvxTrace for more
>   information

On this line in BookView Class :

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.View_Hello);

    }
```

I am not getting that when the same DataLayer is getting the data from XML file then why does it get ViewModel resolve issue in the Android build .

Comment: Try stepping through your BookViewModel constructor in a debugger to see where the exception is occurring?

Comment: Actually it got resolved now , the issue was that I had an xml file saved as a resource in ViewModel PCL which could be accessed from windows phone but not from android . So ,I made it available online and accessing from there and serializing . But then too , does not sound perfect to me that why cant we access the saved resource file from android .

Comment: You can access resource files in Android - ask a good question about how to do this and someone will be able to assist (tag it with PCL, Xamarin, MonoDroid and C#)